# Ссылка на функцию внутри функции

Tags: python

В *Python* любая функция - это объект. Но как тогда получить ссылку на этот объект внутри функции? Никакого `self` функция внутри себя не видит.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А что мешает использовать имя функции?

```
>>> def foo():
...    return foo
... 
>>> foo()
<function foo at 0x7f7cd66fba60>
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x7f7cd66fba60>
```

Если имя функции неизвестно, то получить его нельзя. Подобая функциональность [была отвергнута](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3130/).

Но, как говорится, если очень хочется, то есть несколько вариантов. Я бы не рекомендовал так делать без особой на то нужды

Через `inspect`:

```
import inspect

def foo():
   print inspect.stack()[0][3]
```

Через `sys`:

```
import sys

def foo():
    print sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

Получить метод, зная название функции, можно через функцию `globals()`

**Upd**

**Внимание!** Согласно документации [не все реализации python могут включать `sys._getframe`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe). Это функция для внутреннего использования интерпретатора CPython и может не работать на других. Используйте на свой страх и риск

Comment: А если я хочу обобщить и не знаю имя функции ?

Comment: @faoxis никак. [Предлагалось](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3130/), но было отвергнуто

Comment: @faoxis вообще есть костыль для получения имени вида sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, но я бы не советовал

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
import inspect

def foo():
   name = inspect.stack()[0][3]
   print(name)
   print(globals()[name])

foo()
```